# Inequality between Dirichlet and Neumann eigenvalue for Sturm Liouville problem

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, eigenvalues

Consider the following Sturm Liouville problem on an interval $[a,b]$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} x}\left[p(x) \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x}\right]+q(x) y=-\lambda w(x) y$$
for given coefficient function $p(x),q(x),w(x)>0$. Here we can assume they are smooth. One can consider two sets eigenvalues
$$0<\lambda_{1}^D<\lambda_{2}^D<\lambda_{3}^D<\cdots<\lambda_{n}^D<\cdots \rightarrow \infty$$
$$\lambda_{1}^N<\lambda_{2}^N<\lambda_{3}^N<\cdots<\lambda_{n}^N<\cdots \rightarrow \infty$$
where $\lambda_i^D$ are Dirichlet boundary condition and $\lambda_i^N$ are Neumann boundary condition. It is quite easy to show $\lambda_i^N\leq \lambda_i^D$ by the variational characterizations of the eigenvalues. However, it seems that under some condition of $p,q,w$, we will have
$$\lambda_{i+1}^N\leq \lambda_i^D$$
I encounter this when reading some papers, and it says this is well known. Does anyone know a good reference for this type of inequality? Who first found this? Do you have a simple proof?

PS. I googled a little bit and found many works on eigenvalue inequality of this type for Laplacian operator on dimension greater than 1. I am just interested in one dimension and here the operator is more general than Laplacian.

Comment: I do not know but I have two suggestions. In the 1d case, the book by A. Zettl is a very detailed treatment of Sturm Liouville problems, maybe you find it there. For the Laplacean, Filonov's proof of the inequality is the easiest and could be adapted to more general Sturm-Liouville operators.

Comment: Thank you for your comment